# Stack driver GCP

Tags: logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

Where I can view the stack driver logs in Log Explorer GCP console?

I didn't get any information regarding this. Previously there used to be a console saying Stackdriver Logging.

Is stackdriver logs decommissioned now ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackdriver has evolutioned into [Operations Suite](https://cloud.google.com/products/operations?hl=en). This suite includes the following features:

- Cloud Monitoring
- [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs)
- Error Reporting
- Cloud Trace
- Cloud Profiler

In order to view your Google Cloud resource's logs, you can use the [Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface). It's a very powerfull tool provided with filtering and querying options. You can even create custom metrics based on these logs, custom alerts and log sinks to route the logs you specify into your own Cloud Storage Bucket.

I hope I could provide helpful information. Regards!